# Dynamically loaded class from jar and classpath

Tags: java

I'm dynamically loading a class from a jar file and invoking it. (see [here](https://github.com/tebeka/nuclio/blob/java-runtime/pkg/processor/runtime/java/src/main/java/Wrapper.java#L67) and [here](https://github.com/tebeka/nuclio/blob/java-runtime/pkg/processor/runtime/java/src/main/java/Wrapper.java#L158)).

This works well with plain java code, however when I try to use other classes that are embedded in the same jar, I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
```

I tried adding the jar I'm loading the class from to the classpath (either by -cp or setting CLASSPATH environment variable). Both failed.

I've checked and ObjectMapper is in the jar, if I compile a the below with this jar and then run it with this jar in the classpath it works.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class t {
    static public void main(String args[]) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper);
    }
}

$ javac -cp build/libs/curler.jar t.java
$ java -cp build/libs/curler.jar:. t 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@1efee8e7
```

I'm using

```
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

You can see an example of how I invoke the code [here](https://github.com/tebeka/nuclio-dev-utils/blob/master/run-java-wrapper).

Comment: Why is it NoClassDefFound error and not the ClassNotFound Error?

Comment: @amitmah That's what Java spits out

Comment: Is `ObjectMapper` in the same jar that your `URLClassLoader` is loading?

Comment: That will answer your question

Comment: @tsolakp yes it is